# Individual Coloring Scale of Each Column in VegaLite Highlight Table

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I am working on a VegaLite highlight table which you can find by clicking [this link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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). For this table, I have 7 different numeric variables I need to visualize  in the columns, with their values being shown by url. My data looks like the following:

```
{
        "url_domain": "[commit.unclaimed-us-assets.com]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 42,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 383,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      }
```

After transforming the data to have cleaner column names and to turn 6 of the variables into percentage values, I have been able to get them all on the columns by performing a fold function within the transform area like so:

```
{
      "fold": [
        "People",
        "Web Visit %",
        "Page Load %",
        "Email %",
        "Phone %",
        "Name %",
        "Bounce %"
      ],
      "as": ["Title", "Value"]
    }
```

My trouble now is that I have 1 absolute variable that can go into the thousands, and 6 other percentage basis values that have wide-ranging percent values. Therefore, I want my highlight table to have an individualized color scale for each column, but so far I only have been able to color the column that has the absolute amounts and none of the other columns, when I want each of the columns to be colored on their own individual scales. Here is the part that colors them, as I am not sure where to go from here. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
"layer": [
    {
      "mark": "rect",
      "width": 1000,
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "Value",
          "aggregate": "sum",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "legend": null,
          "scale": {"range": ["#ecf9ff", "#c6efff", "#7ad9ff", "#42caff"]}
        }
      }
    }
```

[image: Picture of Vega Lite Editor]

Answer (score 1):

You can provide conditioning in color or fill encoding and depending on the condition provide a color. I tried giving scale inside condition but it was not working with `condition[]`, it only worked with a single condition. Below is the config or refer [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289ABE2yGrIAEAIXVwkAazYNMFq7fuZFIAO41l9NCChymEgmcOruOpiCcGigmHAAHm6oANogAMIM6layjgDqcHA2pobGZpbWdg7uTACepgDKOHBQNABmNFCmAGLBgplqIAC6SkjCZHr+cDmh7so1aPwAjAAMSq2B+TRkWH5MbILK7gGCbGHoAMQALK1iAJwA7ChrgfU0AF7RqIsAzM85fgBZQIQULqJCYBQQJCyCD8EGaVogAC+SgCsnaZBiICQ8RoECxZE0h1QmHUDDgSh0UBs5mhxJACTi-yRKJU4JQqFAxFG5PxKVAmUEAH1lEZghNkgEEAg6JQGLIoIJggg4Mp+AxYUgICDMBBKFLBu4PHAmELiHi6HzVhgtUKcEgyHAhSckMTrYhemhrTgYHJPpcAExKWRIFVepR7eVQT7euBsHBRNDfAAcvxANAQCcQUyCOjkQswNSafgyWRz4QzTtaYLD6FL2TyBRsyIUAvUwtFpT8yRssjYHiiykdlHWbGUECCmah2rxQQVcEopzIhqUxtN5oglvDNogdodTpdbqUHpogm3Pr9aDEwdDMYj9nn57jWbQqaUGazKpy4N0BaLn3STIGwrFUhWrW8SyAnNTHyQoWzbDsxRMbspQQeU6BqOUFSVSs1Q1fgtR1PUDSNE0zQtXVtxgW17UdZ02FdbcTzPL4lAvWRPm+W4b1ra1I0fViQCaeNE1QLjr3TTMoi-XNf0LYs6yg-5KUrMCawA+toNg5sUQQkUkIlKZ1H2QQsMVZVVThHQ0L6WFYGaGx9SMFdPDIjct1Qa1qN3WiDwYo8GWMFjvV9Di0EWIMQBDXj7yjO8hOfUTk0ij9pJzH983kjSlLcFTQPA2tALLHIYKbeCQEFfSu3QZJfQ8TA2EdIIZwnaFoychAXLXcjN0ozylG8vc6MPJigvPULPkWZMePi-joyfETPgDAA2NNUuzb881kP8FKK4C8qrdTIOKxs4N0ir2yq8VuxMdYzJwlU1QnDMGFs-h7OpDqurciirQGmj93oxj+sCz0QfYybLhm7c5vi4SX1QZN7nfKSNtkzL-2O-aQGsw6IMUk7SrO1sLsQ6qQGSBAajhZotv4ZN+F9DUTDIRd1GXUj11+qiAeG-zRrBxY2ImpNkuhkHYfCtjEqW5blpS1GZIy7asqx8sDrU-G9q0srzsqztrpqwjZ0oOAxhoJhTww43WvnNmOdXH7er+nchr84H3TGwSIbQZGovxviH3m72ZfCxYhckz90q2nbspOkC8cKzSSu08r9YM7skBwBNMJBKAtuTG253apdvq552eZ8wGRpB5ipaEkWvmW8XA7i+v4dExZbmmyO0s2uTMYJ7Hcc1pOcqJnSSfT8nklUOJ1BlDjKDzgui7ahdS85nqPK83n3YCuvwcbiKW9igTY0W8KxD99alZj1Wh-VnHVIKuOGwntPLoN5CjZazAsMQAmNgNQlZ-3XvbMu28+q7yrnzD2x4vYhUvGJU+IBJbg1DqgS41pb7RwHrtZOuVn75SOo-FOusp5fwzr-TcE5KB1Qak1NedsSKO3Ljvf6sD94C1PONZBkVoqzSDnDTB3woa9zRsrWOatlLEMTm-HWxM9Lf0MsoBgUBwQLjNlsC2VtCzMJLuzSB7loGcLdkDA+iDhbIObv7GKaDhELQRuHG+is8EYwITlBOo8FHkKUaTK6P8KbrAXvQ+wm5ZBkAIsoc07VWGuXYaY12vkLE8OCtYsKqABEBzPsHC+CNuISLvvg3xRCR6vxkadSeyjqEUyQJGf+IJZDsDBGA+cTAphwHaLqCBW8TEu0GikmunswZIMydk+x6D8md1cVHfuHjSneIqWQqpn8yaGwpivXQhc2nRkWL0thUCBl71SbXKxDdkER0ETDRxGDL6oFsbg+ZKtB7a1keU0hbzVl6yoTPE4tBZBhOZpE6JsSFzxO6v0yu5jhkINGRkpaqCpnS3uSsFGcz0YvM8fHDWyyvkfx+esoJyQcBWHtFYIFESokdI4t0vUm9DlQpBoM6u-MznwouZk601yJa3OmZxCSTzMXSJWUsz5hCCWUKJRKEJCBKUsxpuoMF9KjF9O5syk5sLQa8KPpcpFfKUXOJwW455Iqvliq1hK1OhLAkSlumwe6Fk8Kam1HAHpEKnYcOSay+B2r0mcvijy1u59DWiQVhiqRD9zW4vFePa1UrbWZwaZQR6HRghDgYN4awuzwXOTVRXDVXDTkjJ1WMwNOSHFtzuc49FfdhVRsIRasehN401JnpucYDAcAAKksA0BtDi5wAkAyhJRzoVDLZSW-1PsQZBtySI1FtbJH31eY2mNlq40ULbRs5ITB-nL1ptsgxQ6DmjqZTAmFk64WloRfXOdlaQ0JUXUU9xWLFnrube-VtASVHdgbAGfsHFzZ7tzZ1fNXqWVwMsRymd3KK3IqfTWl9pqG1eI-aUyV27iX-JMAe-OR6c37JHZC9VF6J2+sPmW7c96EMd0Rch+tq60NyJ8ZUzDP7anJCLnh1ehHT0kYLWRn10Gb0BrvfBg1iGw1LuKQsypTaMPfunju+prge1AJAelHNlx+OeqSZB7h7LROwf1VW-laBw11sjUxnFLG8VWq3RxmesqeMEYHevIjqrGWkbMeRkT07G5wcmZJujFmZOvrNWuuzsaW2OeU8Slz8pAEnE09+bTunEnHKLVqyjt7BI0ZC5gyzy6SnyfQ2xpTvyd0dtkF2lNqo03eDIJm1Qx6vrgf05qq9fq+FctM4+0LWTwsoZs8PF+MWv1xaq8SrOOd6vKEaxmrNbWPWZfHcJtJvXy3BbM6Gyaw3GPYrGyQjdsX-HxYlKSNNzgc0ZbHYWy9FHzkzquRJ3bUn9sMes0dp+HzTuTfO9NmVpw5VbLkDs9z84Ax3fPb5jbRmAt6rsUI97g2I5Cu+++6L-3FHVKczupLvbUvNUh3smHPnvVQc27qvryObmo8wejk1h2sd-c-bjtZiaap7saq58Hx6dPEb01lx7-mtvUbewNxnB3Mdlex+zvxOlBislJNCCAsq0DJFAO0QQ88sTtDNvSNn0RjwAEcGCjAq7rc6Ou9echAAbg4fgMcruLGbi3LFzUshJhowQUBXqaL8MocEDA5WhZGHyEAAAFUO51ff+6VHEPwxl5TKAABRp4agAOVDx09Qafg+YFD5QATloACUBBC-F7o2XgAVCsZYjeK8N-cFqPw+QmCmAAGoUVMAAUnKvHgPSf0Ap9kOnzPbAc8IDzwXkPcqDMWIr1XsPMs68N6bwQFvEe-BR-3KYAAMv5fvg-RgJ8D6Ph8E-s+59CHPovcrmLL-n5QGv9fG+b+39iSPABRIKJ+48z9h8AIx9r8p9b988V9X8Jpn8H9X81938P9m9G9W9I8o8JoACfcgDE8QCr8M8b8Z878oDBFYDq8ECN9lhkDlhUC-As9bxMDQAh8cDk88DJ9p9Z8oDYZSDV9Fp18P9KCt8UCd90BzBhEGCHd9hiRUgY9L4lAO9u9e8B8lA99HRD9j8lCQA-9egT9lCMCNC6CVQdCQBRC4oT9hhv9NcQAAAVOgRMJQLvHkaIZXcw5AdQZsdAOIRIdwKYAIBbSJLEeIfXGgQ3PwGwyIE3HGV5PsReS3JQGQdQJIFQNQaMcfFmVvXEPkWIWwz4WrQQQQJQJUDpQQAAQUiVEmtEKLNi6A2DgC2B2HQD2CdwKPqTNjSH2FOD8CuBuAeCeBAEqMEGqJyFeA+HCgqJaMED32UD8MxFQAklOGCP+A8PjGRFZHmHt0d3pAu3CCiKMBMFiJAHiKSG12CKd3QBkJfEpFeXN2hAiB-FIHcFOFUDOCSOgCmGmIeJwD8AgFDxbGxAyKxAiFElyPyL6PGNKLIHKOaKKMGMwE2G2ESMaMOChNaPaOeK6LuEeHcH6JhOGMmjGKKMmPeNmJZFZCVBqBmH5BAFcPcJACsHziNG8F8C+A-2PAVDHDSPWNPBYlACiEdHHzQGBLWBOPpAcL6AiKjWuJyDoDuIiLRAWy2k11iDUESKgLCKiFMAAF4NTTAAByeQnvXqfvHU7Y3aSU24nQe4pQbkMUzo1oO05MZaRYcqOICcIPF-NUuATU7UnUlQz0o-V0I0k0gCM06Ui0iI608kTopAAMAoR0505Ut0uAj0r03UrQ08QMy400i3KU2SS0kACMgCc4VoZaZMW4JAJ086F0lU907IlMn0vQ40zM4M7M80mgPMgszoqAVoW4W4RYFASshM9AVU2srU3Ugwz0vvRsyIrMm40Mts8Mxwzs+pFYCskmKsxM4vZM0cnUkw+cDM6c5s2c3Mhcm0i4AoaMpAZMZEcw6AUYT4UAMESJT4VIc4Zobsu09wc4KAZaLpD8pQc4R4ZQW4P8kAK4AMDRD85XEkkmakgE15TwohdYIY94T4HuJCxIoEHIeEMECEKEGERVNoVvMYCYFIvXVkHw9k-w+3BCoIkI9AUUyMkk5XIAA).

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Domain Breakout Breakout",
  "width": "container",
  "title": {
    "text": ["Current Week Domain Breakout", "by Specific Failures"],
    "align": "center",
    "dy": -10,
    "fontWeight": "bold",
    "color": "#4f597a",
    "fontSize": 13,
    "font": "Montserrat,sans-serif"
  },
  "config": {"axis": {"grid": true, "tickBand": "extent"}},
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "url_domain": "[commit.unclaimed-us-assets.com]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 42,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 383,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[knowledge.foodstampsassistance.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 5,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 83,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[community.unclaimed-us-assets.com]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 1,
        "phone": 39,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 1,
        "people": 395,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[enroll.unclaimed-stimulus-check.com]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 12,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 82,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[howtogetassistance.com]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 18,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 263,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[info.unclaimed-stimulus-check.com]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 14,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 87,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[my-section-8-housing.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 1,
        "phone": 382,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 1,
        "people": 2662,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[assist.eligibilityassistance.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 1,
        "phone": 7,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 1,
        "people": 111,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[apply.section8assistance.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 1,
        "phone": 16,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 1,
        "people": 198,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[determine.section8assistance.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 12,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 157,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[assist.unemploymentassistance.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 3,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 40,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[assist.howtogetassistance.com]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 2,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 34,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[educate.eligibilityassistance.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 6,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 117,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[form.housing-advice.com]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 2,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 9,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[about.seniorassistancebenefits.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 2,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 17,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[section8assistance1.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 1,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 6,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[login.housing-advice.com]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 2,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 10,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[prepare.housing-benefits.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 0,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 35,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[form.housing-services.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 1,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 10,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[info.unclaimed-us-assets.com]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 0,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 2,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[about.medicaidguideassistance.com]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 0,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 1,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[signup.unemploymentassistance5.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 0,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 1,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[blog.section8assistance5.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 1,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 1,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[rent2owneligible.com]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 0,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 1,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[login.section8assistance1.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 0,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 2,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[assist.section8assistance1.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 1,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 2,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[about.unemploymentassistance4.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 0,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 2,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[form.section8assistance1.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 0,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 2,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[form.unemploymentassistance4.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 1,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 2,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[signup.medicaidguideassistance.com]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 0,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 2,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[apply.medicaidguideassistance.com]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 0,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 1,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[tricareassistance.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 1,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 1,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[form.section8assistance2.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 1,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 1,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[unemploymentassistance1.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 0,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 1,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      },
      {
        "url_domain": "[blog.section8assistance4.org]",
        "web_visits": 0,
        "has_page_load": 0,
        "email": 0,
        "phone": 0,
        "name": 0,
        "bounce": 0,
        "people": 1,
        "implementation_type": "Current",
        "time_frame": "Current Week"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"filter": {"field": "time_frame", "equal": "Current Week"}},
    {"filter": {"field": "implementation_type", "equal": "Current"}},
    {"calculate": "datum.people", "as": "People"},
    {
      "calculate": "round((toNumber(datum.web_visits)/datum.people)*10000)/100",
      "as": "Web Visit %"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "round((toNumber(datum.has_page_load)/datum.people)*10000)/100",
      "as": "Page Load %"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "round((toNumber(datum.email)/datum.people)*10000)/100",
      "as": "Email %"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "round((toNumber(datum.phone)/datum.people)*10000)/100",
      "as": "Phone %"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "round((toNumber(datum.name)/datum.people)*10000)/100",
      "as": "Name %"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "round((toNumber(datum.bounce)/datum.people)*10000)/100",
      "as": "Bounce %"
    },
    {
      "fold": [
        "People",
        "Web Visit %",
        "Page Load %",
        "Email %",
        "Phone %",
        "Name %",
        "Bounce %"
      ],
      "as": ["Title", "Value"]
    }
  ],
  "mark": "text",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Title",
      "type": "nominal",
      "sort": "descending",
      "axis": {
        "title": null,
        "labelAngle": 0,
        "labelFontWeight": "bold",
        "labelColor": "#4f597a",
        "labelFontSize": 10,
        "labelPadding": 5,
        "orient": "top"
      }
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "url_domain",
      "type": "nominal",
      "sort": {
        "field": "People",
        "type": "quantitative",
        "order": "descending",
        "op": "sum"
      },
      "axis": {
        "title": null,
        "labelAngle": 0,
        "labelFontWeight": "bold",
        "labelColor": "#4f597a",
        "labelFontSize": 10,
        "labelPadding": 5
      }
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "rect",
      "width": 1000,
      "encoding": {
        "fill": {
          "legend": null,
          "field": "Value",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "condition": [
            {
              "test": "datum.Title == 'Web Visit %'",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "value": "#fff861"
            },
            {
              "test": "datum.Title == 'Page Load %'",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "value": "#a2ee61"
            },
            {
              "test": "datum.Title == 'Email %'",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "value": "#f689a1"
            },
            {
              "test": "datum.Title == 'Phone %'",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "value": "#cf991a"
            },
            {
              "test": "datum.Title == 'Name %'",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "value": "#cab101"
            },
            {
              "test": "datum.Title == 'Bounce %'",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "value": "#eea2a8"
            }
          ],
          "scale": {"range": ["#ecf9ff", "#c6efff", "#7ad9ff", "#42caff"]}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "fontSize": 8,
        "font": "Montserrat,sans-serif",
        "align": "center"
      },
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "Value"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that answer! Very helpful to get me going down the right path, but I still unfortunately need to have it operate as a continuous color spectrum according to the values within that column and not just have it colored differently. Do you think the best way to do that would be to create 7 different visuals at this point or are there any other options I can try?

Comment: I tried giving scale in each conditions but it was not working, I think multiple scales are not allowed in conditions. Other than this I don't have any other approach available. you can wait for others response.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create independent scales for each column, you can create them as separate views. If you set `"resolve": {"scale": {"color": "independent"}}`, each view will get its own scale.

Here is an example (also available in the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVICUJNohSZ8gL5LM2pLIgAzNtoRoA2qADuNWcrZvT1A2HH17WQBrRRAkCHCHaKsAXRtQJxpBTDhtNHSaOEFlBKiYrLQAJgAGKxSlGCg5E0xgkF9lejQxKts6QTh9AAkABRjkbWj0bIAPFqU4WUblPzI8kBmWzRAMwuL0QdcIOBxAnJjMAE8cAfRZNgQ-JD0bEAu1naKS6Nsrm5BXZayJ4xJDTGjxVCyBiCQQvRqCVzvAqffaHY6nXI-a76ACODAcmDoahopDK5AWeyhMNqaTaNA6MC6PXWfT+AFlhgBxMamSbrOCzGILJYrNYbJG7fRszJwCAAfWu2jlnKeCPkWL+dweQOeSjeWw+exAEW+61++gBjz0SlB4LQVNhSnhiINyKN0v68sVytVcnO5vQeIJRMJpKU-TIFPt0NhtQUPnpnVQ3V6mH6+gA8toaLR1SBxnzxfNFmxAastuLXZL0Fmc35-djbvcrSAXvr8tXjYkG39LTqQWCIQ64WwEbkqyiQLXc2TI-5o9TasklBAcEgoKLUMztLLR6SttAnjdQM7xyA-MpjhSFi0aUA)). Note that I hid the legends so that the columns are closer to each other.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "transform": [
    {"window": [{"op": "rank", "as": "rank"}]},
    {"filter": {"field": "rank", "lt": 20}}
  ],
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "width": 50,
      "title": "HP",
      "mark": "text",
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "Horsepower", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "rank", "type": "ordinal", "axis": null},
        "color": {"field": "Horsepower", "type": "quantitative", "legend": null}
      }
    },
    {
      "width": 50,
      "title": "MPG",
      "mark": "text",
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "rank", "type": "ordinal", "axis": null},
        "color": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon", "type": "quantitative", "legend": null}
      }
    },
    {
      "width": 50,
      "title": "Origin",
      "mark": "text",
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "Origin", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "rank", "type": "ordinal", "axis": null},
        "color": {"field": "Origin", "legend": null}
      }
    }
  ],
  "spacing": 0,
  "resolve": {"scale": {"color": "independent"}}
}
```

[image: table view for the spec above]